# How to transpose row to column in spark/scala?

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I'm new to spark, but I can't find the answer to a simple question: How to change row to columns? For example, I have data like:
Type | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |... | Col60
1    | 12   | 3    | 4    |... | 87
2    | 1   | 5   | 6    |... | 90

I want to change it to like

Type | ColName | Value
1 | Col1 | 12
1 | Col2 | 3
1 | Col3 | 4
...
1 | Col60 |  87
2 | Col1 | 1
2 | Col2 | 5
2 | Col3 | 6
...
2 | Col60 | 90

I've tried to search many places, but there is no answer exactly like what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Hive, you can use `lateral view` with `explode` by getting the columns into a `map`.

```
select type,colName,val
from tbl
lateral view explode(map('col1',col1,'col2',col2,'col3',col3)) t as colName,val --fill it with all the columns from the table
```

Spark SQL also has `lateral view` and `explode` which can be used.

Comment: Thanks!! But how can I save the table in spark? Use hiveContext.sql("*")?

Comment: And is there a programmable way to do this?